# Scheduled event won't fire

Tags: actions

I'm trying to set up individual, one-time schedule events in a plugin. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the events to fire. I'm using the Cron View [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cron-view/) to see what's in queue, and the events are added and remove themselves totally on schedule. I never, however, receive the email I've set to send in the action's target function (simply in order to test the event, there will be more in there later). I have tested the function outside of scheduled events, it does work. Here's some code:

```
GLOBAL $new_workshop_id;
$new_workshop_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

function send_reminders() {
 GLOBAL $new_workshop_id;
 wp_mail('my@emailaddress.tld', 'Automatic ID: '.$new_workshop_id, 'here it is!');
}

if (!wp_next_scheduled('send_reminder_emails_'.$new_workshop_id)) {
 wp_schedule_single_event( time()+30, 'send_reminder_emails_'.$new_workshop_id );
}

do_action( 'send_reminder_emails_'.$new_workshop_id );
add_action( 'send_reminder_emails_'.$new_workshop_id, 'send_reminders' );
```

One thing I'm suspicious is the placement of do_acton and the function itself, `send_reminders()`. The above code is within some if statements checking for POST vars, so it's possible that the function can't be accessed by the CRON job - so where should I put the function? I've tried right at the top of the plugin file. From what I've read, do_action should call the function and execute it wherever you have put do_action, but I guess I need to know where to put `send_reminders()` in the first place so that it's accessible, by either the cron job or do_action.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cron argument usage looks weird. The insert id will return garbage by the time your function is called.

By the same token, I believe better schedule it always, with the id argument, on insert, if this is for logging. Else you'll be throttling your logs, basically.

Lastly, are you sure that `wp_mail()` is working?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your first two points... cron arg usage? logs? Could you please elaborate/reword? I have tested the `send_reminders` function on its own, including `wp_mail`, so yes I do know that that works. Thanks for the response!

Comment: re the first question, by the time the cron gets fired, your variable is no longer set (because it's a different process) to whatever it had been used with. re the second, you can pass arguments to the wp_schedule_single_event() function; give it an insert_id argument, and pass it to your function. Contrary to what the WP codex says, the actual signature is: wp_schedule_single_event( $timestamp, $hook, $args = array()). (see wp-includes/cron.php)

Comment: Ahhh, that's helpful - the documentation is very skewed with regards to passing arguments to the scheduled action. However, even when I remove the variable from the action and just use hard coded text in the email, it still never sends.. any ideas for what else I can out in that action to see if it works with something other than `wp_mail`, perhaps? I have also tried `mail`.

Comment: For logs, I personally append to a file...

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I still can't get the function to run. I have the function itself successfully writing a 'completed' message, but it never happens when the cron task disappears from the cron monitor. I've tried putting the function in my plugin's file and in my theme's functions file.

Comment: Try using the core control plugin, to debug the cron job. It allows to run scheduled events, among other things.

Comment: Allowing me to rerun events is helpful, however it's just proving over and over that my function is not running. It has to have something to do with my placement of the function. Now, I have the function at the top of my plugin file, below the plugin info, with no if statements enclosing it. The scheduling code is within an if statement, I've tried putting the function there as well as just `do_action( 'send_reminder_emails_'.$new_workshop_id )`, but nothing works. I've also tried the whole thing with a static action name instead of `'send_reminder_emails_'.$new_workshop_id`, no luck.

Comment: Again, your arg usage is not good, and I'm suspecting your flow is not good either. By the time your cron hook gets used, your ID variable contains random garbage (probably null). Hook into the action regardless of the ID, and pass the ID as a cron argument instead when an insert actually occurs.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to give that a shot, but I still don't totally understand the problem - I'm only registering ACTIONS with that ID, and according to the cron schedule, they're being created just fine - the target function doesn't attempt to use the ID variable at all. Anyways, I'm give it it a shot, definitely worth a different approach. I'll report back, thanks!

Comment: Ok, that's a negative - it still absolutely will not run. If I put `do_action( 'send_reminder_emails' )` among my scheduling code, it fires, but it will not fire when I run the task. Totally baffled.

Comment: Again, your key issue is a workflow problem. If you don't use a cron arg, then by the time you the send_reminder_emails_$id hook gets fired, your code is not registering the appropriate action for that php instance; it's registering an action on send_reminder_emails_ instead. That simply can't work. Also, no offense but this site just isn't a support forum...

Comment: I think I have it working - it looks like the key was partially what you said, using a single action name instead of a dynamic one, and also I needed both add_action and the target function to happen outside of my scheduling code - so they're beside each other at the top of the plugin file. Passing arguments made using a single action possible, much better. I know this isn't a support forum, but it is about finding answers, you should never feel obligated to continue support, especially if you don't think I'm getting it - but I greatly appreciate that you stuck with it! Thank you!